# Почему при вытягивании используется rebase, а не merge?

Tags: git

Создал новый репозиторий, запушил на github.
Симулирую параллельную работу в обучающих целях.
Делаю `git pull`, обнаруживается конфликт `both modified`.
Я изменяю содержимое файла, добавляю его в индекс, а в инструкциях (были выведены в git status) до было предписано использовать `git rebase --continue`. Но разве стратегия слияния по умолчанию не merge?
[Здесь](https://www.atlassian.com/ru/git/tutorials/using-branches/merge-strategy) написано: "Рекурсивная стратегия позволяет обнаруживать и обрабатывать слияния с переименованием, но на сегодняшний день не может использовать обнаруженные копии. **Эта** стратегия применяется по умолчанию при выполнении команд **pull или merge для одной ветки**."
И я не понимаю, почему у меня по умолчанию происходит перебазирование.

Comment: возможно, у вас в конфигурации `pull.rebase=true`. см. вывод `$ git config pull.rebase`

Comment: даже наверно лучше проинспектировать всё, начинающееся на `pull`: `$ git config -l | grep ^pull`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
pull.rebase = true
```

Когда это я успел)